# Is not there a program / library to parse common unix utilities text based output, such as lshw, iwlist, dmidecode?

Tags: text-processing, utilities

I have a .net core application that makes use of several unix utilities to query hardware data, such as `lshw`, `iwlist`, `dmidecode`.
`lshw` supports `json` output, so it's not a problem.
I currently write my own parsing code, I am surprised that there is no tool to parse such tools outputs.

I am correct ?

Comment: You are correct. Could the question possibly be reformulated as "Are there tools that provide the same information in JSON format"? (if JSON is the format that you want to work with).  Or possibly, "How do I query the kernel for this information directly without going through tools that I don't want to write parsers for?"

Comment: @Kusalananda: feel free to edit and rename to whatever you feel suits most. I personally would not follow your first suggestion because I am not specifically interested in JSON formats - although they would certainly come in handy,  nor the 2nd suggestion because I personally do not feel it conveys the same meaning. I am interesting in learning about work someone already did that parses all these very-common-kernel-tools outputs.

Comment: There might be libraries in some language or other (although that seems unlikely, these are just a basically random list of tools that are not connected to each other, I doubt anyone would bother writing a library to parse them instead of a library that can generate the same data), but if there is, it is doubly unlikely for it to exist in .NET of all things. .NET is mostly a thing of the Windows world, so I would be very surprised if such a library existed.

Comment: @terdon: I am not looking for something specific to .NET. But I agree, I mean, on the one hand indeed I was not able to find such tool, on the other hand - it is surprising in a way since these tools seem to provide the standard way for querying this or that kernel piece of data - meaning the same job is being done repetitively by hundreds of users. I think I made the point for... me myself writing such a thing ? oops :-)

Comment: Well, normally you wouldn't use these tools if you're writing a program that depends on this sort of data. You would instead use the `/proc` filesystem or the relevant Linux API call or whatever. You are trying to use external utilities that do not have any standardized format and are each probably developed and maintained by different people so I would expect there to be any parsing library for them. :/

Comment: You are right again, I guess. No doubt, I come from a non Unix universe, and I am ultimately trying to "port" unix stuff to external environments. Yes, one alternative was going through iwlist source (specifically) and try to understand from which files in the file system it queries the data from. Yes, I also expect the output not to be standardized throughout these tools. My current choice is to try to write a simple .net program as generic as possible that will - luckily work with at least the tools I am mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://www.nongnu.org/txr) is a language for extracting information from loosely structured, multi-line text.

Let's take the output of `dmidecode` as an example and turn it into a list of JSON objects:

```
$ txr dmi-data.txr  dmi-data
{"Version":"VirtualBox","Address":"0xE0000","Characteristics":["ISA is supported","PCI is supported","Boot from CD is supported",
                                                               "Selectable boot is supported","8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)",
                                                               "CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)","ACPI is supported"],
 "desc":"BIOS Information","Vendor":"innotek GmbH","ROM Size":"128 kB",
 "Release Date":"12/01/2006","Runtime Size":"128 kB"}
{"Version":"1.2","Wake-up Type":"Power Switch","desc":"System Information",
 "SKU Number":"Not Specified","Manufacturer":"innotek GmbH","Serial Number":"0",
 "Product Name":"VirtualBox","Family":"Virtual Machine","UUID":"CE1C8E2B-F6C0-4E0B-9E40-7958B29D121F"}
{"Version":"1.2","desc":"Base Board Information","Features":["Board is a hosting board"],
 "Type":"Motherboard","Chassis Handle":"0x0003","Contained Object Handles":"0",
 "Manufacturer":"Oracle Corporation","Serial Number":"0","Asset Tag":"Not Specified",
 "Product Name":"VirtualBox","Location In Chassis":"Not Specified"}
{"Version":"Not Specified","desc":"Chassis Information","Boot-up State":"Safe",
 "Type":"Other","Security Status":"None","Manufacturer":"Oracle Corporation",
 "Lock":"Not Present","Serial Number":"Not Specified","Thermal State":"Safe",
 "Asset Tag":"Not Specified","Power Supply State":"Safe"}
{"desc":"OEM Strings","String 2":"vboxRev_140239","String 1":"vboxVer_6.1.14"}
{"desc":"OEM-specific Type","Header and Data":["80 08 08 00 2B C3 33 00"]}
```

The program looks like this:

```
# dmidecode @nil
@(skip)
Table at @nil

@(collect :vars (obj))
Handle @nil
@desc
@  (require (not (mequal desc "Inactive" "End Of Table")))
@  (bind obj @(hash))
@  (repeat :gap 0)
@    (cases)
@\t@prop: @value
@      (do (set [obj prop] value))
@    (or)
@\t@prop:
@      (collect :gap 0)
@\t@\t@valueline
@      (end)
@      (do (set [obj prop] (vec-list valueline)))
@    (end)
@  (until)
Handle @nil
@  (end)
@  (do (set [obj "desc"] desc))
@(end)
@(do (put-jsons obj))
```

and the `dmi-data` file contains:

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
10 structures occupying 450 bytes.
Table at 0x000E1000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: innotek GmbH
    Version: VirtualBox
    Release Date: 12/01/2006
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 128 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: innotek GmbH
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    UUID: CE1C8E2B-F6C0-4E0B-9E40-7958B29D121F
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: Virtual Machine

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
    Location In Chassis: Not Specified
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 13 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Type: Other
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 126, 42 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 126, 15 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 126, 28 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 11, 7 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: vboxVer_6.1.14
    String 2: vboxRev_140239

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 128, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        80 08 08 00 2B C3 33 00

Handle 0xFEFF, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```